# WPF, change separate color based on value

Tags: c#, wpf, matrix, datagrid, grid

I try change separate cell color based on value in wpf datagrid.I use datagrid 2d.

```
      <DataGrid Name="c_dataGrid"
       RowHeaderWidth="0"          
       ColumnHeaderHeight="0"
       AutoGenerateColumns="True"
       AutoGeneratingColumn="c_dataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn"
       SelectionUnit ="CellOrRowHeader"                                       
       IsReadOnly="True">    
       </DataGrid>
```

I need change cell color when value is example 1.

Answer (score 0):

Edited to more accurate:

```
<DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Text" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: program writes error : Item collection must by empty before using ItemsSource.

Comment: Use search, there are much same topics about this error.